# Problem with .htaccess rule to same initial route

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have this two rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/model-1/ models.php?id_model=1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^brand/model-1/exit-page/ exit.php?id_model=1 [QSA]
```

The first rule is to go to the model and the second rule is to go to the exit page.

The problem is:

If I go in my browser to: **brand/model-1/exit-page/** it takes the first rule **brand.php?id_model=1** and the second rule is ignorated.

It seems don't read the second rule because the initial route is similar:

- brand/model-1/
- brand/model-1/exit-page/

I hope you can help me please! :)

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy.
That means your first rule matches you second scenario too.

If you add `$` at the end, you should match `brand/model-1/` precisely.
It's still safe to make the trailing slash optional, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/model-1(/)?$ models.php?id_model=1 [QSA]
```